# Why does async await throw a NullReferenceException?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, asynchronous, async-await

My code looks something like this

```
var userStartTask = LroMdmApiService.AddUser(user);
 // .... do some stuff
await userStartTask;
```

When `AddUser()` throws an exception, it bubbles up as a `NullReferenceException`.  It doesn't wait for await.

But if I structure the code like this...

```
var result = await LroMdmApiService.AddUser(user);
```

Then exceptions get caught properly. Can someone tell me what's going on here?

Here is complete code that shows the issue.  What is the best practice for such a scenario?

```
class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CallAsync();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static async void CallAsync()
    {
        var task = CallExceptionAsync();
        ThrowException("Outside");
        await task;
    }

    public static Task CallExceptionAsync()
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            ThrowException("Inside");
        });

    }

    public static void ThrowException(string msg)
    {
        throw new Exception(msg);
    }        
}
```

Comment: Please provide a short but complete example demonstrating the problem. It's hard to help you with only this much code.

Comment: Look at userStartTask as a contained method, contained by the Task you are trying to spin off.  If there is no way for the task to return inside the method via the "var result" then it must return to the method layer instead.  This means the exception is not contained in the "var result" rather it is thrown at the method layer.

Comment: @JohnPeters, I was following the example from Microsoft here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh696703.aspx

Comment: @Anish you need to show the code where the exception is thrown. (e.g. `LroMdmAdiService.AddUser()`).

Comment: Why is this question being down-voted? It's a very relevant issue, and quite honestly a bug in C# that await throws a NullReferenceException when the task is null - at least an ArgumentNullException would be much more precise with some details about the problem. I hit this issue and waster hours debugging before I came here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This code

```
var result = await LroMdmApiService.AddUser(user);
```

is practically identical to this code:

```
var task = LroMdmApiService.AddUser(user);
var result = await task;
```

> When AddUser() throws an exception, it bubbles up as a NullReferenceException. It doesn't wait for await.

`AddUser` probably looks like this (where `_service` is `null`):

```
public static Task AddUser(User user)
{
  return _service.AddUser(user);
}
```

This will cause a `NullReferenceException` to be thrown *directly*, not placed on the returned task.

If you always want your exceptions to be placed on the returned tasks, then make every task-returning method `async`:

```
public static async Task AddUser(User user)
{
  return await _service.AddUser(user);
}
```

However, you should consider whether you really *want* to do that. `NullReferenceException` in particular is a code bug; it's not an exception you should ever catch or care about in production. [To use Eric Lippert's term, it's a boneheaded exception](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx).

In my opinion, it doesn't matter where boneheaded exceptions are thrown - whether they're thrown directly or placed on a task - because these exceptions are only for the developer, not runtime.

Answer (score 3):

I found the cause.  Two exceptions were getting called.  Before await and inside the task.  The first ended the thread and returned execution back to the caller.  So when the 2nd exception (from the task) was raised, it had no parent thread.

```
var userStartTask = LroMdmApiService.AddUser(user); //1) An exception was being thrown inside AddUser()
 // .... do some stuff 2) And another exception was being thrown here
await userStartTask;
```

Exception thrown inside killed my app with the NullReferenceException bec/ the method it was called from no longer existed.

Since everybody is asking for examples, here is a simple example which shows the same issue.

```
class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CallAsync();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static async void CallAsync()
    {
        var task = CallExceptionAsync();
        ThrowException("Outside");
        await task;
    }

    public static Task CallExceptionAsync()
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            ThrowException("Inside");
        });

    }

    public static void ThrowException(string msg)
    {
        throw new Exception(msg);
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to check is for Objects that *are actually* null.

This code was giving me a NRE:

```
Plan plan = await db.Plans.FindAsync(id);
if (plan == null)
{
    return HttpNotFound();
}
ViewBag.AdviserId = new SelectList(db.Advisers, "ID", "Name", plan.AdviserId);
PlanPage planPage = new PlanPage();
planPage.Plans.Add(plan);     //The List<Plans> object hasn't been instantiated ( = new List<Plan>();)
return View(planPage);
```